# How do I check to see if a column that stores an array 'includes' a parameter passed in to a 'where'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have a `Question` model that has the following column:

```
#  refactor_rules          :string           default([]), is an Array
```

That stores values like this:

```
>> Question.offset(1).last.refactor_rules
=> ["dry", "concise"]
```

I would like to write a `where` query that checks to see if any question includes a single parameter/option in that `refactor_rules` attribute.

I tried this query:

```
@questions = Question.includes(:user, :answer).where(refactor_rules: params[:rule])
```

But that didn't work. It gave me the following error:

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "dry"
```

I know it's something with AR is expecting a `string`, but is instead getting an array.

I just can't quite figure out how to check each value for that attribute against the string "dry" or "concise" that is passed in.

**Edit 1**

**Question Model**

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :accepted_answer, class_name: "Answer", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Answer Model**

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :answered_question, class_name: "Question", foreign_key: "accepted_answer_id"    
end
```

Comment: Try `Question.where(["'refactor_rules' = ANY (?)", params[:rule]])`

Comment: @Santhosh Nope...same thing. Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you please share models to see associations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about Postgresql array column, take a look at [this blog post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/07/rails-4-and-postgresql-arrays/) which nicely summarizes using this type of column under rails.

You should be able to find records with any matching `refactor_rule` with the following syntax:

```
Question.where("? = ANY (refactor_rules)", params[:rule])
```

See the [`ANY` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN20327) for more docs.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I had checked out the above blog post before, in fact that's what encouraged me to use the array data type. It just didn't help me with the `where` query. Your answer was very useful though. Thanks again!